# Clearing the sessionStorage of a newly opened tab in IE11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11, sessionstorage

I (successfully) use the following piece of code to open a link in a new window, and clear its sessionStorage:

```
var win = window.open(url, "_blank");

if (win) {
    //Browser has allowed it to be opened
    win.sessionStorage.clear(); //<-- This line triggers the error.
    ...
}
```

However, this gives me the following error in IE11:

```
(SCRIPT 65535) unexpected call to method or property access
```

This works without fault in Firefox, Chrome and Edge. I am unsure why IE11  gives this error. *url* is a properly defined variable.

I have already tried to wrap the code like so:

```
if (win) {
    $(win.document).ready(function() {
        win.sessionStorage.clear();
        ...
    });
}
```

because certain answers I have found while looking for the error message I get were about variables that were not declared properly / not loaded yet. This does not solve the problem, though.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I can't reproduce this error in IE11. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: I am unsure why the error does not occur for you - the only thing I can think of is that the URL I use is over https, not http. Does this help you?

Comment: There's still no error for me with https. Here's the [exact code that I put in an HTML file](https://jsfiddle.net/xm6x88w1/1/). Do you get an error with it? If not, please share some code which produces the error.

Comment: I am now on my way back home from work. I will try your code tomorrow and will try posting some code that gives me an error if your code runs fine for me. The website that I run the code in is behind a login, so if I post the url that gives me an error here, you can't reproduce that either. For test purposes I will also use the code you provided in my own website to see if the error is somehow related to the domain. I'll add another comment when I know more.